# Javascript form validation pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate that two characters and a number were correctly input.

```
var studentValid = /^[MTWTF][AL][1-9]$/i;
if (studentValid.test(studentTemp.value))
{
    alert("true");
}
else
{
    alert("false");
}
```

Yet everything I enter turns out false?

Comment: What do you want to validate to true, but gives you false? For example the value `'MA9'` will give you true. The problem is with your regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your regexp (`/^[MTWTF][AL][1-9]$/i`). What this tells you is that you first want one of the characters M,T,W,T or F, and after that either A or L and finaly a number (and nothing before or after this).

So for example

> ML4, WA5, FL9

will give you true
while

> AM9, ML0, MMA5, MA99

will give you false.

Is this the pattern you are trying to match? There is nothing else wrong with your code and a valid value will give you true, for example:

```
var studentValid = /^[MTWTF][AL][1-9]$/i;
var value = 'MA9';
if (studentValid.test(value))
{
    alert("true");
}
else
{
    alert("false");
}
```

When working with regexp, it can be very usefull to use a tool to help you build it, check out https://regex101.com/r/A5FOIh/3 where you can try your different `studentTemp.value` to see if they match.

Comment: Thanks for that link, very helpful.